# Handle result sent back to android studio when result from web server is empty

Tags: php, android

I am working on a android app where I query my api and return values.

This works fine, however i'm  a bit stuck when the query finds no values (no results in the data base)

This is part of my api that returns results

```
if (empty($rows))
        {

            //deliver_response(404,"Item not found",NULL);
            $encode = array("List" => $rows);
            $json_response=json_encode($encode);

        }
    else
        {
            $encode = array("List" => $rows);

            $json_response=json_encode($encode);
                    echo $json_response;
        }
```

and part of my android code

```
   if (status == 200) {
                    HttpEntity entity = httpResponse.getEntity();
                    String data = EntityUtils.toString(entity);

                      if (data.equals(""))
                      {
                          Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"No Results Found",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                      }else {
                          JSONObject jobj = new JSONObject(data);


                          JSONArray jsonArray = jobj.getJSONArray("List");
```

When I place a breakpoint on `String data = EntityUtils.toString(entity);` data is `data="\n\n"` however, when i have,`if (data.equals(""))` and `if (data.equals("\n\n"))` the if is ignored and it enters the else.
Was wondering if anyone could assist me in rectifying this.

Thank you

Comment: Dude your code does not make any sence...First you only send a response when you have rows, so why do you create a $json_response if you are not calling echo? if you do call echo you will get {"List":""} as reponse. So you can check if you have values after spliting the string in java.

Comment: @Gatunox totally missed that echo...sorry

Comment: No problem, If that was the problem please vote the comment up.

Comment: it doesn't show. good luck

Comment: ohh i see the tiny 1, that's it.

Answer (score 0):

I think it’s more advisable to have message key in your web service response, hence message  key will have always message from server i.e. no record found, success, failure (in case of some error in query execution)

In android you should always check message, and based on that you can show respective message to user.

example json response

> {   "list": [
>       1,
>       2,
>       3   ],     "message": "No Record Found" }

Comment: you mean like deliver_response(404,"Item not found",NULL);